# IIS Redirect to new URL

Tags: angular, redirect, iis

I'm trying to redirect users of my Angular 7 website from an old url to a new url as below:

https://www.example.com/v1/page/NjUxMzExNC83MzQx

to

https://www.example.com/v2/page/NjUxMzExNC83MzQx

I'm using IIS 8 but I can't work out what setting to put in to make this change, whilst maintaining the data in the url that will be different per user, ie. the "NjUxMzExNC83MzQx" part

I've tried the below web.config settings in the "v1" version to pass users on to "v2" but this doesn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
  <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="v2/" exactDestination="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this rule.

If you need to redirect v1 to v2, please select type="redirect" instead of rewrite.

```
  <rule name="redirect rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/v1(/page/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="v2{C:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
                </rule>
```

[image]

Edit:

```
   <rule name="redirect rule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/v1(/page/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <serverVariables />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/v2{C:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
                </rule>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I think it's nearly working, but not quite.  When I enter in the url, I can see that it turns from this https://www.example.com/v1/page/NjUxMzExNC83MzQx to https://www.example.com/v1/v2/page/NjUxMzExNC83MzQx and then to this https://www.example.com/v1/ all within about half a second Could it be that it's conflicting with the angular rule?  I've got this one first then the angular one.

Comment: The edited version doesn't work I'm afraid, it just repeats /v2 lots of times.  Also I've removed the angular rule now as that's not necessary and it just stays on  example.com/v1/v2/page/NjUxMzExNC83MzQx now

Comment: @fosbie I know where's the problem. Did you host v1 and v2 as virtual application right? If so, the redirect would misunderstand the relative path v2/{C:1}.  I have updated the rule. Please check if it works

Comment: Just for clarity, I did just add an "s" to make http into https